# Lock screen turns monitor on and off

Tags: 18.04, display, lock-screen

When I enable the lock screen the display starts to fade away as expected but shortly after it turns off it gets reenabled. This continues in a loop till I log in again.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 with the amdgpu driver. I have two monitors attached.

Update: I recently switched to a Nvidia GPU and the problem does not occur anymore. It seems like this is a problem with the amd driver.